# How can I make this plunker runnable?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, plunker

I am trying to check out my ionic project which is built through angular js but unable to make runnable it on plunker. It's working on my local machine, with all rpm packages, etc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app='starter.controllers'>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-touch.js"></script>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 


    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers.js"></script>


    <script src="services.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" style="background-color: #E6E6FA; ">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Link to Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/XW06IgbL29n8fBLWsxSb), also need your suggestions to improve it

Comment: Can i have to provide my Git link

Comment: Add the code in the question and provide a link to plunkr. Not just a link.

Comment: @ Marcus H - added html code here only u can see all code on punker link

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is not loading because plunker needs https. Just change the url to `src="https://code....`

And you are using ionic, so you should include ionic library.

```
<script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i added it as u suggested

Comment: Add all required files, you are using ngDraggable but .js file is not added. jQuery still won't load, it must come from HTTPS source or be stored in plunker.

Comment: Plunker doesn't actually _need_ `https`. The way things work is that if the editor (or embed) is loaded via `https`, the preview will also _need_ to run as `https` (because of mixed content policies). Since the preview is running as `https`, the preview assets follow the same mixed content policies.

Comment: @Omkar - I hope so. I built Plunker.